# How would I go about creating a Toroidal coil?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Hey I'm wondering how I would go about creating a toroidal coil in Blender?
I don't even know where to begin.. I know a torus would perhaps be a good start but then how do I wrap the coil around it?
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the extra curves addon if there is any pre defined primitive for this? There may already be a preset, if not you can easily create it by deforming a spiraled curve around a circle.

Comment: There's quite a few steps, so I've made this video: https://youtu.be/WiQn0WrAgTU

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Add a new mesh plane, adjust its dimensions so it matches the desired size of the coil square section.

In *Edit Mode* move it along the X axis the desired distance you want for the larger radius.

Erase the outer edge and rotate both vertices along the Z axis a desired angle $α$ so it roughly forms a spiral.

Use an *Array* modifier set to *Object Offset* and as offset use an empty rotated about the Z axis $α$ degrees just like the vertex previously.

Complete the array, apply the modifier, and in *Edit Mode* use *Remove Doubles* so it becomes a continuous loop.

You can then transform into a curve objects to bevel and add thickness as desired.

[image]

To give it a more smoothed square section set the curve type to *Bezier* select all handles and make them *Automatic* first, then converto to *Free*. Once as free you can scale them all individually to adjust the smoothness of the squircle.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Add curve extras toroidal spiral**

Install Add Curve Extra

[image]

*`Add > Curve > Curve Spirals > Torus`*

[image]

In front view <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> add a plane inside the torus to be our magnet profile.

[image]

Spin the plane 360 degrees in top view

[image]

Add and apply a shrinkwrap modifier on the spiral, to the magnet.

[image]

Bevel the curve with a bezier circle, (scale down and apply to match wire)
[image]