# How can I model a helical helix, helicity on several levels, with a script?

Tags: scripting

The shape I wish to model is something like a

[image: helical helix]

That is helicity on (at least) two levels. I would prefer an algorithmic way, since the parameters of the model will be changed.

Comment: Have a look at add curve extras addon. Has a number of spiral options.  Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139523/how-to-model-the-curly-cable-part-of-the-phone

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57615 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87281