# Impressing a spiral on the surface of a cone

Tags: modeling

I'm attempting to model a hybrid French-Turkish drop spindle and have most of it modeled out from a sketch and prototyping a simple Turkish style model first. The only difference I'm aiming for is a spiral impressed shaft top for the French addition.

[image: Example of my goal.]
Example of a French spindle top, this is my goal.

[image: Example of the Turkish shaft and the cone base I'm using to create the French shaft.]
Example of the Turkish shaft and the cone base I'm using to create the French shaft.

I've tried using a boolean modifier to create the spiral using spiral bases I've found on Thingiverse (allowing for the CCs to do so of course), but this hasn't worked and frankly I don't like relying on someone else's work to accomplish my own, I'd rather have an understanding of how something is achieved.

I'm very new to 3d modeling and I suspect this problem may have a simple solution, but I lack the technical vocabulary to find what I need just searching online. If anyone can help me understand what functions would be useful in this case from a modeling perspective it would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: You can get a very similar shape started fairly quickly by drawing a profile curve of the notch in the shaft, using a Screw modifier to make it cylindrical, then increasing the Screw value for that modifier so as to give it an actual corkscrew slant as it follows the cylinder around and around, apply the modifier, so that the object becomes real geometry, and then use a lattice as a modeling aid, to taper in the narrower end of the shaft. Granted, you will still have a lot of editing work to do afterwards.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201725/winding-coil-using-a-conical-shape-for-3d-printing

Comment: Ah! Perfect, thank you! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the example isn't linear, you could make a profile and bend it

1. Create the shaft profile as a flat plane. Subdivide it evenly using loopcuts.
2. Give it a *Simple Deform Modifier > Bend* and target an *Empty 01*
3. Add *Simple Deform Modifier > Taper* and target *Empty 02*

By moving *Empty 01*, change the diameter of the shaft.
By moving *Empty 02*, change the taper direction.

Then just apply the modifiers, fill the gap you're done.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, the visual aid here and step by steps are a huge help! I'll try this out this evening =)

Comment: Happy to help :). If you get stuck anywhere, feel free to let me know.